# Why does the space is required before %c in order to make the code work?

Tags: c, loops, do-loops

**THAT'S REALLY INTERESTING**

**wrong code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    char another;
    int num;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
            
        printf("\nWant to enter another number y/n ");
        scanf("%c", &another);
    }while(another == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
Enter a number: 23

Want to enter another number y/n
C:\Users\Shivam Singh\Documents\Let's C\From Book\Ch3>

**To differentiate between the wrong and right code please look at the %c. The only difference in both the codes is a space which is just before %c in the right code.**

**right code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    char another;
    int num;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
            
        printf("\nWant to enter another number y/n ");
        scanf(" %c", &another);
    }while(another == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:
Enter a number: 23

Want to enter another number y/n y
Enter a number: 54

Want to enter another number y/n n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is required for `scanf()` to consume the pending newline left in `stdin` by the previous `scanf()` that read a number and stopped consuming characters right after the last digit. Without this space, `scanf()` will store the next byte into `another`, most likely the newline that was typed by the user to submit the number.

Note that you should also test the return values of `scanf()`to detect invalid input or premature end of file.